# Can you help me to identify this helicopter?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification, rotorcraft

I came across this helicopter and am wondering what the oblong things on either side of the helicopter are, parallel to the front-back axis, offset from the main body.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a better photo? Maybe some zoom & other image enhancements?

Comment: @curious_cat How's that?

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Comment: @andrewmh20 Can you tell when and where u came across that heli?

Comment: @aeroalias Israeli skies, and I see from the link below that Israel had some CH-53D's.

Comment: @andrewmh20 I had a doubt it was not a Pave Low as they've been retired. Your comment confirmed it. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The helicopter is a Sikorsky CH-53 (probably an 'E' model).
According to [this site](http://www.sikorskyarchives.com/S-65H-53D%20SEA%20STALLION.php), the two sponsons holding the fuel tanks are also the place where the landing gear retract.

EDIT: Probably not an 'E' model as the 'E' model has a seven-blade rotor, while the one in this picture doesn't. 
I'd say this is a 'D' model or an MH-53 'J' model.

Comment: the drawing from wikipedia matches the shape quite well: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/CH-53D_Sea_Stallion_Drawing.svg/2000px-CH-53D_Sea_Stallion_Drawing.svg.png

Comment: @Federico, edited, because of model mismatch...

Comment: @MarcoSanfilippo CH-53D makes sense with location --see comment on question.

Answer (score 13):

The helicopter is a S-65C-3 Yas'ur (Albatross). It is a CH-53D version similar to USAF HH-53C Pave Low. Here is a photo of the same.

[image: CH 53]

The identification is based on the following:

- Six bladed main rotor
- The sponsons which hold the fuel
- The only variant of CH-53D with in-flight refueling probe in service is the Israeli version. All others (HH-53 and MH-53) have been retired. CH-53E has refueling probe, but it has 7 blades.

Israel ordered 36 of these,of which around 23 are still in service.